# outer join issue with sub query-Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, outer-join

I browsed through solutions for this issue, unfortunately couldnt get any help. Here I am getting "column may not be outer joined to a subquery" issue. Afaik With clause wont help here because subquery here reference table B.PFB an extract of issue statement.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM ( ( A a1
    JOIN A a2
    ON a1.temp = a2.temp1 )
    JOIN C c1
    ON c1.column1  = a2.column1
    AND c1.column2 = a2.column2
    AND c1.column3   = a2.column3 )
    LEFT JOIN C c3
    ON c3.column1   = a2.column1
    AND c3.column2  = a2.column2
    AND c3.column3    = a2.column3
    AND c3.column4 =
    (SELECT MAX(c4.column4)
    FROM C c4
    WHERE c4.column1 = a2.column1
    AND c4.column2   = a2.column2
    AND c4.column3     = a2.column3
    ) ;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I did not realize that Oracle does not support subqueries in `on` clauses.  In this case, you can easily fix the problem using analytic functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM A a1 JOIN 
     A a2
     ON a1.temp = a2.temp1 JOIN
     C c1
     ON c1.column1 = a2.column1 AND
        c1.column2 = a2.column2 AND
        c1.column3 = a2.column3 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT c3.*,
             MAX(c3.column4) OVER (PARTITION BY c3.column1, c3.column2, c3.column3) as maxcol4
      FROM C c3
     ) c3
     ON c3.column1  = a2.column1 AND
        c3.column2 = a2.column2 AND
        c3.column3 = a2.column3 AND
        c3.column4 = c3.maxcol4;
```

I am guessing that you could use analytic functions elsewhere in the query to simplify the logic as well.

Comment: I am not much in to analytical functions.Thanks a lot.It worked.